# PHP Changelog code profiling

Tags: php, version

Does anyone know where there is a nice place to view the changelog for PHP? Functions specifically? I've been trying to read this and it's proving confusing, http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

I need to update one of our live servers from 516 to something newer, but I need to know which functions are dead, deprecated or otherwise not in use, so that I can profile the code on the box.

Any ideas please? Or is there an automated service which can parse a project's source and tell you what functions are specific to which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [5.1 to 5.2 migration guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php). Pay special attention to the [backwards incompatible changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.incompatible.php). And here's the [same guide for 5.2 to 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php) and it's [BC incompatible changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php). Also, with PHP 5.3 they started [deprecating stuff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) which can cause E_DEPRECATED warnings.

I have written a coding standard for PHP_CodeSniffer that checks for anything that throws an E_DEPRECATED on PHP 5.3. Unfortunately I cannot share it (as it was written in my Boss' time). But, it took me just 2-3 hours to write. It shouldn't take you much longer :-)